# Passive for "Don't have"

Tags: grammar

I need to ask a question like as "How many stations don't have electricity yet"
How do i ask this question in a passive mode?

1. How many stations are not electrified yet?
2. How many stations have not been electrified yet?
3. How many stations have not electrified yet?

Which sentence is more accurate here and why?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, to be able to be changed into passive, a verb must be *transitive* - it must have a 'doer', an action and a 'done to'. Usually, 'have' is *intransitive* - 'having' isn't really 'doing' anything, so there is no action and no 'done to'. So, it is impossible to change 'How many stations don't have electricity yet?' into passive.

Your sentences 1. and 3. are both active - they imagine the stations being able to 'be' electrified and 'have' electrified (all by themselves, with no-one doing the electrification). Your sentence 2. *is* passive, but it is not the equivalent to your original sentence. It is the short passive equivalent to 'How many stations have *they* electrified yet?'. The full passive equivalent is 'How many stations have been electrified *by them* yet?'.

Answer (score -1):

From grammatical point of view:

**"For how many stations electricity has not been had, yet?"**. (But this is not idiomatic?)

From idiomatic point of view:

**"For how many stations electricity has not been restored, yet?**